# Access denied to list created via ListTemplate in a feature

Tags: 2007, list-template, feature

I've created a feature to create an instance of a custom list.  The provisioning part of my feature is:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ListTemplate
    Name="ClientList"
    Type="10001"
    BaseType="0"
    DisplayName="Client List"
    Description="Templat for a list of clients."
  />
  <ListInstance
    Title="Client List"
    Description="List of Clients."
    TemplateType="10001"
    Url="Lists/ClientList"
  />
</Elements>
```

The list seems to be created OK (if I check its settings, it has the correct content type and columns), but when I try to view it, I get the message:

> Access denied.  You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

If I create the list through Central Administration, using the list template that I provisioned in the feature, I also get the Access denined message.  If I create any other list, e.g. a Custom List, there's no problem.  So I think something must be wrong with my list template, but I don't know what!

My schema.xml was produced by [Imtech's list export stsadm command](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/export-list-definition-free-stsadm-command/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I realised what the problem was -- I was missing the SecurityBits attribute from the ListTemplate definition.

With:

```
<ListTemplate
  Name="ClientList"
  Type="10001"
  BaseType="0"
  SecurityBits="11"
  DisplayName="Client List"
  Description="Template for a list of clients."
/>
```

the Access Denied issue goes away.